# How is TURN authentication secure?

Tags: webrtc, stun, turn

So I have followed a bunch of tutorials in how to setup a coturn server and I do not understand why a TURN server should have authentication when I still have to pass the username and credentials to the RTCPeerConnection web API thus revealing the credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Most services vend temporary credentials. You could either manage that yourself or do use TURNs [Long-Term Credential Mechanism](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5389#section-10.2). This allows you generate credentials that are time limited.

You can see an example [here](https://github.com/pion/turn/tree/master/examples/turn-server/lt-cred) from Pion TURN.

Comment: But I still need to pass username and password to the client which makes it completely open for anyone to steal them and use my turn server in their own application.

Comment: You are right about that. All you can do is limit the length of time the credentials are valid for. You could also require users authenticate to get the credentials and other things you enforce.